raise FileNotFoundError( FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'DisableCopyOnRead' in binary running on
raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'DisableCopyOnRead' in binary running on LAPTOP-DBPNOMK8. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) tf.contrib.resampler should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the experimental_io_device option in tf.saved_model.LoadOptions to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.
how to solve this error

Could you please provide more information about the TensorFlow version you're using, how the model was saved, and what format is it in? Referring to this issue, might help to resolve the error.
